# JQuery Ajax not working when two browser tabs are open on the same domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very strange problem when working with JQuery and PHP AJAX.

I have a form that submits via AJAX and it works fine. The problem is, when I load another page from the same site in another browser tab, my ajax request no longer works in my other tab.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#step-edit-form").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    //Update order in the database
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax.ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

          if(data.success == 0) {
            $('.message').html(data.message).fadeIn()
            console.log(data.message);
          } 
          else if(data.success == 1) {

            $('.save').hide();
            $('.message').html('Saved Successfully').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            formmodified = 0;
          }
          },

          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error) {

             console.log('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' + 
            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
            'xhr.statusText = '  + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
            'error = ' + error);
          }
      });
  });
```

**I get this in console:**

> xrs.status = 200
>   thrown error = SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>   xhr.statusText = OK
>   request = undefined
>   error = undefined

The PHP returns nothing at all.

Like I said, this only happens when I load another browser tab on the same domain, otherwise everything works fine. I've tested in both Chrome and FireFox, same issue in both browsers.

I have these two pages open in the two tabs:

**Tab 1:** http://localhost/sbs/admin/edit-step/18 (This is my tab with ajax)

**Tab 2:** http://localhost/sbs/ (I load this tab after at which point the ajax in my first tab no longer works properly)

Comment: Please note that your local host will not be available to public unless you deploy it in a public domain.

Comment: Yes, I only pasted there to give an idea of what I'm doing.

Comment: So add debugging to the serverside and figure out what is going on. My guess is there is an issue with some sort of cookie/session value.

Comment: @epascarello You were correct. It turned out to be an error with PHP sessions. I've been pulling my hair out for hours over this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the error 'Undefined end of input' which means there are some cases when you are getting wrong response then expected.

**Possible causes for this error**

- Your code is broken from server side. Just like using **exit** statement
- You are missing comma(,), braces({,})
- Your code returns **null** data

That is not a issue of opening in new tab, It's an issue of unexpected data

Answer (score 0):

i think contentType missing in your ajax call.

Please add below contenttype in your ajax request.

```
     "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

this is issue in you ajax call OR server side run time error or parameter related issue to call service.

ajax request always call on multiple tabs for same domain.